# Откостерить — значение и употребление слова

Tags: значение-слов, семантика, глаголы, устаревшие-слова

Можно ли употребить глагол **откостерить** в значении *отругать*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре Д. Н. Ушакова:
костери́ть, -рю́, -ри́шь, *несов., кого-что* (обл.). Бранить, ругать.

В словаре Т. Ф. Ефремовой:
[костери́ть](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%D1%80%D1%84/wd/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — *несов. перех. разг.-сниж.* Сильно ругать, бранить.

Есть глаголы ***от***ругать и ***от***бранить (присутствуют в словарях), что же мешает образованию глагола ***от***костерить (в словарях отсутствует)? Ничего.
Слово есть, используется нечасто, исследователи языка относят его к устаревшим (разговорным или диалектным).

462. ОТКОСТЕРИТЬ, -ю, -ишь, -ят', СВ. Отругать кого-либо ([из диссертации](https://www.dissercat.com/content/kategoriya-vida-russkogo-glagola-v-govorakh-tambovskoi-oblasti)  «Категория вида русского глагола в говорах Тамбовской области»).

> Есть также слова, использование которых найдено только в художественной литературе, и об их значении пришлось догадываться по контексту. Например: **откостерить — отругать,** чикилять — хромать, бзыкать — капризничать, смыкануть — украсть <...> покрытая (голова) — в косынке, распокрытая — без косынки, убратая (девушка) — нарядная, длинногачий — высокий, разеватая — рассеянная и т. п.

(Исследовательская работа «Казачий лексикон – уходящая самобытность нашей семьи»)

*Старосте храма это невдомек — он мужчина энергичный, и забот у него хоть отбавляй: и с администрацией кладбища нужно "порешать" вопросы, и рабочих **откостерить** на чем свет стоит, и парой слов с нищими перекинуться* (МК, 1999).